# adding elements of a vector to an unordered set

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-set

Is there an easy way to add all the elements of a `vector` to an `unordered_set`? They are of the same type. Right now, I am using a for loop and was wondering if there is a better way to do it

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you're constructing the unordered_set then:

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::unordered_set<int> s(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Comment: what should be done next? I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to build the set. E.g. ```vector<int> v; set<int> s(v.begin(), v.end()); for(...) // here I push back elements for( auto i : s) cout << i;``` doesn't print anything, and debugging shows the set is empty.

Answer (score 29):

Forgive me if my syntax has any minor bugs, but you can try the [std::copy function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/), its meant for this purpose.

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::unordered_set<int> s;
std::copy(v.begin(),v.end(),std::inserter(s,s.end()));
```

Comment: `std::inserter` is required to insert into an associative container.

Comment: yup, i knew i missed something, fixed.

Comment: does s.end() remain valid even if the container rehashes?

Comment: if v is empty then an 0 will be added to s!