# How to convert vector to set?

Tags: c++, vector, set

I have a vector, in which I save objects. I need to convert it to set. I have been reading about sets, but I still have a couple of questions:

- How to correctly initialize it? Honestly, some tutorials say it is fine to initialize it like `set<ObjectName> something`. Others say that you need an iterator there too, like `set<Iterator, ObjectName> something`.
- How to insert them correctly. Again, is it enough to just write `something.insert(object)` and that's all?
- How to get a specific object (for example, an object which has a named variable in it, which is equal to "ben") from the set?

I have to convert the vector itself to be a set (a.k.a. I have to use a set rather than a vector).

Comment: `set<Type> s(v.begin(), v.end());` is the easy way.

Comment: @larsmans No. I need to convert vector to be a set, fully. I cannot have both of them in my code.

Comment: @sharth No. I can only use set. What I am trying to say is how to use set correcly?

Comment: All the answers here involve using the constructor, is there anyway to do this on an already constructed set?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850927/adding-elements-of-a-vector-to-an-unordered-set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't told us much about your objects, but suppose you have a class like this:

```
class Thing
{
public:
  int n;
  double x;
  string name;
};
```

You want to put some Things into a set, so you try this:

```
Thing A;
set<Thing> S;
S.insert(A);
```

This fails, because sets are sorted, and there's no way to sort Things, because there's no way to compare two of them. You must provide either an **`operator<`**:

```
class Thing
{
public:
  int n;
  double x;
  string name;

  bool operator<(const Thing &Other) const;
};

bool Thing::operator<(const Thing &Other) const
{
  return(Other.n<n);
}

...
set<Thing> S;
```

or a **comparison function object**:

```
class Thing
{
public:
  int n;
  double x;
  string name;
};

struct ltThing
{
  bool operator()(const Thing &T1, const Thing &T2) const
  {
    return(T1.x < T2.x);
  }
};

...
set<Thing, ltThing> S;
```

To find the Thing whose name is "ben", you can iterate over the set, but it would really help if you told us more specifically what you want to do.

Answer (score 205):

Suppose you have a vector of strings, to convert it to a set you can:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;

std::set<std::string> s(v.begin(), v.end());
```

For other types, you must have `operator<` defined.

Answer (score 83):

All of the answers so far have copied a `vector` to a `set`. Since you asked to 'convert' a `vector` to a `set`, I'll show a more optimized method which moves each element into a `set` instead of copying each element:

```
std::vector<T> v = /*...*/;

std::set<T> s(std::make_move_iterator(v.begin()),
              std::make_move_iterator(v.end()));
```

Note, you need C++11 support for this.

Answer (score 18):

You can initialize a set using the objects in a vector in the following manner:

```
vector<T> a;
... some stuff ...
set<T> s(a.begin(), a.end());
```

This is the easy part. Now, you have to realize that in order to have elements stored in a set, you need to have `bool operator<(const T&a, const T& b)` operator overloaded. Also in a set you can have no more then one element with a given value **acording to the operator definition**. So in the set `s` you can not have two elements for which neither `operator<(a,b)` nor `operator<(b,a)` is true. As long as you know and realize that you should be good to go.

Answer (score 8):

If all you want to do is store the elements you already have in a vector, in a set:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
// fill the vector
std::set<int> myset(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

> How to correctly initialize it?

```
std::set<YourType> set;
```

The only condition is that `YourType` must have `bool operator<(const YourType&) const` and by copyable (default constructor + assignment operator). For `std::vector` copyable is enough.

> How to insert them correctly.

```
set.insert(my_elem);
```

> How to get specific object (for example object, which has name variable in it, which is equal to "ben") from set?

That's maybe the point. A set is just a bunch of object, if you can just check that an object is inside or iterate throught the whole set.

Comment: Well lets say we want to only find an object with specific name in it. How to do it?

Comment: You'll have to iterate through the whole set, something like: `std::find_if(set.begin(), set.end(), [](const YourType& type) { return type.name == "value" });`

Comment: In that case, if this is the only (or almost only) way to search for an element, a `std::map<std::string, YourType>` should be a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a set is just like creating a vector. Where you have

```
std::vector<int> my_vec;
```

(or some other type rather than `int`) replace it with

```
std::set<int> my_set;
```

To add elements to the set, use `insert`:

```
my_set.insert(3);
my_set.insert(2);
my_set.insert(1);
```