# insert vector into unordered set after declaration c++

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, declaration, unordered-set

I'm looking for a way to insert a vector of elements into an unordered set that I have already declared. Say I have code as follows:

```
unordered_set<string> us;
vector<string> v{"green", "dog", "keys"};
```

Here, `us` has already been declared. How can I populate `us` with the elements in vector v with one command (i.e. without a for loop and pushing the elements individually) **after** its declaration?

This similar answer [adding elements of a vector to an unordered set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850927/adding-elements-of-a-vector-to-an-unordered-set) is not what I'm looking for as the unordered set is initialized during declaration.

Better yet, is it possible to populate the unordered set with multiple elements in one command without using a vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an iterator with [insert()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert).

```
us.insert(v.cbegin(), v.cend());
```

No need for the vector as long as the sequence conforms to the [input iterator concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) and returns strings. An array, other set, vector, etc. are all fine.

Comment: would it work with no declaration at all, like just a list of elements `{"green", "dog", "keys"}`. Similar to how an unordered set can be initialized by `unordered_set us ({"green", "dog", "keys"});`

Comment: Yeah, an initializer list would work as well, both during construction and with insert.

Comment: I'm getting the error `calc.cpp:172:23: error: expected expression
    constants.insert ({"e", "pi", "i"});`.

Comment: Insert with an initializer list is a C++11 feature. You’ll need to enable C++11 in your compile options. A piece of advice, though: you ideally shouldn’t be populating the set after the unordered set is constructed. That set should be able to be marked const.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5qUS6Ycc 
Oh, okay. Is it not set by default?

Comment: It’s usually not. C++ compilers always err on the side of caution.

Comment: Pretty sure insert with initializer list was in C++11. [Quick hack code agrees with me](https://godbolt.org/z/j48YxhhM6).

Comment: And I'm dumb. I could have looked it up instead of hacking out code.

Comment: @user4581301 @beta so should the paste work under default compilation settings? currently im just doing `gcc filename.cpp -o output ./output`

Comment: @rjc810 you've forgotten to `#include<string>`. [More quick hack code](https://godbolt.org/z/3fK1xKjhe)

Comment: You need to add -std=c++11 to the arguments.

Comment: Note on the compiler options: add `-Wall -Wextra` to get more diagnostic messages from the compiler. If it can spot potential screw ups you can fix them without having to stumble over them while debugging.  Also consider adding `-O2` or `-O3` to crank up the optimizer. When the compiler optimizes it takes a longer and deeper look at your code in order to optimize it. That longer, deeper look also often spots even more things the compiler can warn you about.